# Oracle query for value matching pattern

Tags: sql, oracle

I have a table `DOCUMENT` with column names `ID_DOCUMENT` and `FILE_NAME`.

I want to find in the table the rows whose `FILE_NAME` follows this pattern: `VA_#NP#_#NA#_#NNN#_#TXT#`.

In the example I would to find the files: `VA_901085_000002_002_.txt` and  `VA_901085_000002_003_.txt`, so the files whom name starts with "VA" and ends in "_.txt"

```
ID_DOCUMENT       FILE_NAME

     1            VA_901085_000002_002_.txt
     2            VA_901085_000002_003_.txt
     3            VA_901085_000002_003.txt
     4            VA_902833_000001_001.pdf
     5            BT_049009-200811281247.pdf
   ...               ...
```

I've tried with this query:

```
SELECT * FROM DOCUMENT WHERE FILE_NAME LIKE 'VA%' AND FILE_NAME LIKE'%_.txt';
```

But the query returns all the files start by 'VA' and contains txt. Where have I gone wrong?

Comment: What do `NP`, `NA`, `NNN` and `#` stand for?

Comment: NP: number of policy, NA: number of insured, NNN: Secuencial number

Comment: We could drop '#' and the patron would be  VA_NP_NA_NNN_.TXT

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could do a regex match with `regexp_like()`:

```
select * from document where regexp_like(file_name, '^VA_\d+_\d+_\d+_\.txt$')
```

This defines a valid file name if it matches the following pattern (entirely):

- string `'VA'`
- followed by an underscore (`_`), then a series of digits (`\d+`)
- then another underscore, and a series of digits
- one again and underscore and digits
- finally, an underscore, and string `'.txt'`

Answer (score 0):

How about `SUBSTR`?

```
SQL> WITH test (id, name)
  2       AS (SELECT 1, 'VA_901085_000002_002_.txt' FROM DUAL
  3           UNION ALL
  4           SELECT 2, 'VA_901085_000002_003_.txt' FROM DUAL
  5           UNION ALL
  6           SELECT 3, 'VA_901085_000002_003.txt' FROM DUAL
  7           UNION ALL
  8           SELECT 4, 'VA_902833_000001_001.pdf' FROM DUAL
  9           UNION ALL
 10           SELECT 5, 'BT_049009-200811281247.pdf' FROM DUAL)
 11  SELECT *
 12    FROM test
 13   WHERE     SUBSTR (name, 1, 2) = 'VA'
 14         AND SUBSTR (name, -5) = '_.txt';

        ID NAME
---------- --------------------------
         1 VA_901085_000002_002_.txt
         2 VA_901085_000002_003_.txt

SQL>
```

---

Problem in your code is that you used an underline `_` which is a search wildcard character (just like `%`), but which is used for exactly one character. It means that you should **escape** it (see line #14):

```
SQL> WITH test (id, name)
  2       AS (SELECT 1, 'VA_901085_000002_002_.txt' FROM DUAL
  3           UNION ALL
  4           SELECT 2, 'VA_901085_000002_003_.txt' FROM DUAL
  5           UNION ALL
  6           SELECT 3, 'VA_901085_000002_003.txt' FROM DUAL
  7           UNION ALL
  8           SELECT 4, 'VA_902833_000001_001.pdf' FROM DUAL
  9           UNION ALL
 10           SELECT 5, 'BT_049009-200811281247.pdf' FROM DUAL)
 11  SELECT *
 12    FROM test
 13   WHERE     NAME LIKE 'VA%'
 14         AND (name LIKE '%?_.txt' ESCAPE '?');

        ID NAME
---------- --------------------------
         1 VA_901085_000002_002_.txt
         2 VA_901085_000002_003_.txt

SQL>
```